# Typescript does not acknowledge an error when receiving a response from the server to a custom type variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a class and am instantiating it by entering the response of an http request. When working within this class I defined that a variable should be string, however in http request this variable is a number, even so neither my terminal nor the browser console accuse error.

Class Person:

```
export class Person {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(private data: any) {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Ricky",
    "age": "10"
}
```

Instace

```
man = new Person(res);
```

Comment: TypeScript can only check structural / code and semantic typings. It doesn't check types at runtime. If you want to make sure that the data you receive is of a particular type, you will have to do a check against its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript doesn't perform `runtime` checks as it is only a superset of Javascript, what that means is it gets `compiled` to Javascript and then the code is used by the browser. Javascript doesn't have types so when the app is compiled by the browser (at runtime) type checking does not exist.

To check if an element is specific type you need to you the `typeof` construct. Here is a good source for you: [typeof on MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Briefly you can do something like:

```
if(typeof res.age !== "number") {
  return alert('Age is not of type Number')
}
```

Comment: There are also libraries like [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes) that can help validate more complex data structures.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen - thanks, will definitely check it out